# Windows write-fault exception generated by copy-on-write memory page

Tags: windows, segmentation-fault, copy-on-write

I have a Windows application that is working fine on most computers, but on a VM running on an Intel Xeon Gold 6254 processor, I get a write fault exception (0xC000001D) the first time that code writes to a global variable in one of my DLLs. According to a VirtualQuery Windows api call, the memory page being written to has PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY protection set. This is also true on the machines where the application runs fine. My guess is that Windows is supposed to handle this exception by copying the memory page to a new physical memory page before the write occurs, but instead, the exception is being caught by a c++ catch(...) block in one of my other DLLs. The operating system running on the VM is Windows 10 Enterprise. It might also be relevant that our application is written in c#, but uses c++ dlls (legacy code). Note also that I don't have access to information about how the VM is configured, but if this is relevant, I could probably get this information in a few days.

I have run out of ideas for how to fix this problem, so I am looking for suggestions on how to fix this problem or diagnose it further.

Comment: Could this potentially be something to do with Data Execution Prevention being set strictly on the environment you are running in? See specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/data-execution-prevention in the section named "_How Data Execution Prevention Works_"

Comment: *C000001D* - this is `STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION` - *An attempt was made to **execute** an illegal instruction.*. nothing common with write to memory

Comment: @RbMm the header file winerror.h lists the error code part of this (0x1D) as ERROR_WRITE_FAULT 29L, but maybe they are the same thing.

Comment: @Martin I thought about DEP also, except that your link indicates that this should cause a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION exception, which is not what I am seeing.

Comment: @DSimkin - how 0x1D here related ?! you look in wrong direction. look *ntstatus.h*. how i say - you got `STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION`

Comment: @RbMm 0x1D (hex) is 29 (decimal). Windows error codes are defined by OR'ing together a series of standard constants, as explained in winerror.h comments, but I would expect constants in winerror.h and ntstatus.h to be consistent with each other. Maybe STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION usage depends on context. You may be right, though. The instruction executing is:
vmovss xmm0,dword ptr [...], which is not a standard instruction.

Comment: you mistake. *Windows error codes* here unrelated at all. you got `STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION`

Comment: *I would expect constants in winerror.h and ntstatus.h to be consistent with each other.* - no. this is false. when hardware exception - you got status code, not win32 error. you got *vmovss xmm0,dword ptr []* - An attempt was made to execute an illegal instruction

Comment: If an SEH exception gets caught in a C++ `catch` block, you need to update your compiler and/or compiler flags to use standards confirming codegen. Regardless, you are triggering an invalid instruction, which is more common with just about any architecture other than x86. The bug is in your code. Please show it.

Comment: For exceptions like this you should check the [NTSTATUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) documentation. It is `STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION`. My guess is that some instructions that are not supported on the VM are executed. Could you show us the bytes that your application tries to execute? Should be easy if you have a memory dump. EDIT: Just saw the comment about `vmovss`. Does the VM support AVX instructions? That's most likely the problem.

Comment: @icebp I think most likely you are correct, but that's confusing, because I thought Xeon Gold servers supported AVX instructions. On Monday, I will try recompiling my DLL without the AVX compiler option.

Comment: If the problem manifests only when running inside a VM it may be because the Hypervisor does not expose AVX to the VM.

Comment: Rebuilding our DLL to use the SSE2 instruction set instead of AVX2 fixed the problem. I am no longer getting the STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION. Thanks to RbMm and @icebp for their insight. I will try to find out about the Hypervisor in case anyone is interested.